# Can divergences for probability distributions also be used for regular distributions?

Tags: distributions, kullback-leibler

As an example the Kullback Leibler divergence is used to compare two probability distributions. However if you have distributions that aren't described by probabilities, can you still apply such a divergence?
An example for such a distribution is the mass fractions of different products of a chemical reaction.